# creating a curved overlay between sections.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

Hey guys i have the below design to create

[image: need to create this]

Now i usually use a image in such a situation ,but was just wondering if this was possible in any other way I.E. maybe canvas ? I have just started learning canvas , so i can't say for certain.

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/ma1bcchc/)**

HTML:

```
<div class='bnr'></div>
<div class='main'></div>
```

CSS:

```
.bnr {
  height: 35vh;
  background: #990853;
}

.main {
  background: #fff;
  height: 80vh;
}
```

Now how do i add those curved lines apart from using an image ?

Thank you.

Comment: what about an SVG background?

Comment: @Aziz , my motive was primarily something that would take less maintain ace in the future , (this is for quite a big site and that curved line is part of the entire site design) .. SVG for a secoundry option , but then i am open to suggestions ! :)

Comment: An SVG will be easy to maintain, it is a resolution-free image, if you want to adjust it it is as easy as editing the SVG, whereas a canvas will require rewriting JS.

Comment: Play arround with this : [link](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~noam/c-generator.html)

Comment: **A couple of alternatives for you:** Create the design in Adobe Illustrator. Then you can export the design as SVG or you can export the design as a canvas drawing using Mike Swanson's [ai2Canvas](http://blog.mikeswanson.com/ai2canvas).

Answer (score 4):

```
<body onload="draw();">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="985px" height="300px" ></canvas>
</body>

<script>
function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    if (canvas.getContext) {

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(10,10);
        ctx.lineTo(985,10);
        ctx.lineTo(985,245);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(965,270,965,280);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(920,130,640,150);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(530,160,350,190);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(210,220,10,190);
        ctx.lineTo(10,10);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.strokeStyle="#FFF";
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.fill();


        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(10,10);
        ctx.lineTo(985,10);
        ctx.lineTo(985,220);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(965,230,955,255);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(920,130,640,135);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(510,140,350,170);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(190,200,10,160);
        ctx.lineTo(10,10);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.strokeStyle="#FFF";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#990853";
        ctx.fill();



        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(805, 150, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.strokeStyle="#FFF";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
        ctx.fill();



        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(805, 150, 45, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.strokeStyle="#FFF";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ce758b";
        ctx.fill();

    }
}

</script>
```

That how it looks with the previous code :

[image]

Comment: You should not request multiple times the context of the canvas. It wont refresh it. What you want is `ctx.beginPath()`

Comment: You want to tell me this is more maintainable than an SVG background?

Answer (score 3):

You can use canvas for obtain exaclty what you want. Use `fill` for background color and curve.

You can learn more about canvas:

> - canvas : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp
> - curve  : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_beziercurveto.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_quadraticcurveto.asp
> - fill   : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fill.asp
> - a lot of tutorial : http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/

Try my demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/pjxgLkm7/2/

Or

```js
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(0,50,20,50,200,0);
ctx.fillStyle = "#990853";
ctx.fill();
ctx.strokeStyle = '#990853';
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="width:100%"></canvas>
```

Comment: At least in Chrome, it is very blurry. I wouldn't recommend it as a design solution.

Comment: it is an example. I used width:100% it's normaly blur,  but for make what he want, he can follow all tutorial IE: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-shape-fill/ or http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/M5NHN/

Comment: Then you should avoid using css to resize your canvas. (a simple `ctx.scale()` will avoid you the rewriting of all the points https://jsfiddle.net/pjxgLkm7/3/ )